# Is 'A Algorithm' complete?

Tags: algorithm

If 'A algorithm' doesn't have an admissible heuristic still is complete?

I don't understand if 'A Algorithm' without an admissible heuristic can be complete.

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific. What do you mean by 'without an admissible heuristic'?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is an Off-topic question and should be posted in another Stackexchange Site

Comment: @TimoS it would be nice of you to point the OP to that site. Otherwise you will only create frustration. In this case the site is http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Codor in the context of A* an admissible heuristics does not overestimate the distance to the target.

Answer (score 1):

`A*` is complete and will always find a solution if one exists. Have a look at the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Properties). If further the heuristics is admissible and monotonic the algorithm will also be admissible(i.e. optimal).

Comment: I'speaking about 'A' not 'A*'

Comment: @Leo what exactly is `A`?